# Android adb sendevent does not execute events correctly

Tags: python, android, adb

I am trying to record screen events and execute them after for replay.

I wrote a small python script which listens for events,converts them from hexadecimal to decimal,waits for 5 seconds and  executes recorded events with `adb sendevent`.

But for some reason sendevent never executes correctly, sometimes it touches wrong coordinates, sometimes touches for too long also there are problems with delays between touches.

I couldnt understand why this is happening ? What i expect is it should just replay since getevent captured all necessary data needed(?)

```
import subprocess
import threading
import os
from time import sleep

eventsToSend = []
def eventSender():
    while(True):
        if(len(eventsToSend) > 200):
            print("starting to execute in 5 seconds...")
            sleep(5)
            for command in eventsToSend:
                #with open('output.txt', 'a') as f1:
                    #f1.write(command+os.linesep)
                subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            print("done")
            break




        else:
            None

eventSenderStarter = threading.Thread(target = eventSender)
eventSenderStarter.start()

def runProcess(exe):    
    p = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while(True):
        # returns None while subprocess is running
        retcode = p.poll() 
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        yield line
        if retcode is not None or len(eventsToSend)>200:
            print("Executing events...")
            break

print("Listening for events...")

for line in runProcess('adb shell -- getevent  /dev/input/event1'.split()):
    myLine = line.decode().strip()
    splittedLine = myLine.split(" ")
    decimalString = ""
    for index,hexadecimal in enumerate(splittedLine):
        decimal = int(hexadecimal, 16)
        if(index==0):
            decimalString = decimalString+str(decimal)
        if(index>0):
            decimalString = decimalString+" "+str(decimal)

    eventsToSend.append("adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 "+decimalString)
```

Just connect your phone to pc then run this script play with your screen after 200 events it will start replay(be careful because it might press wrong coordinates :P ) .In my case it was

```
/dev/input/event1
```

so you might need to edit event1 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding some small delay between the events you send - `time.sleep(0.5)`. You may have to change the value of 0.5 - try some values until it will work.